# use extract and count function together in mdx

Tags: count, extract, mdx

I have a Mdx query, I want to use Extract and count function together, but it doesn't return anything. anyone can help me?
(I want count people have tradcnt>0, I Use extract because if i don't use it, if a person have multi tradecnt in mention date, that person Be counted multi time but I want to be counted just one time)

```
WITH
 SET [people in first date] AS   
  Filter  
      (  
       {[VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Customer BK].[Customer BK]*[Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1388/06/01]:[Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1388/06/02]},
       [Measures].[Trade Cnt]>0
      ) 

SET [ExtractPeopleFromFirstDate] as
    Extract(
        [people in first date],
        [VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Customer BK]
    )

member [measures].[numberOfPeopleInFirstDate] AS
    Count([ExtractPeopleFromFirstDate])
select

  {} on 0,
   [ExtractPeopleFromFirstDate] on 1 
  from [DVPL]
```

Comment: What does [measures].[numberOfPeopleInFirstDate] return? A value > 0?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Extract` is not required - does `NonEmpty` help?

```
WITH
 MEMBER [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].[All].[DtRange] AS
   AGGREGATE(
    [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1388/06/01]
   :[Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1388/06/02]
   )
 SET [people in first date] AS   
  NONEMPTY  
      (  
        [VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Customer BK].[Customer BK]
       ,(
          [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].[All].[DtRange]
         ,[Measures].[Trade Cnt]
        )
      ) 
 MEMBER [Measures].[numberOfPeopleInFirstDate] AS
    [people in first date].COUNT
SELECT
   {} on 0,
   [Measures].[numberOfPeopleInFirstDate]  on 1 
FROM [DVPL];
```

The answer to Greg's question is important - as if you have `0`s in your cube, as opposed to empty space, then the above is incorrect: `FILTER` might then be an option.